# Launch Android Widget from Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way we can launch the android widget from our application immediately application installation or by showing button(eg:- 'Add Widget') within the application. So it like automatically add widget to our home screen using code.

Thanks
Prakhs

Comment: I searched for the same thing and never found a solution, but perhaps somebody found one.

Comment: I think there is no way :(
Usually I use a "splash screen" with a an information text for the user on how to add a widget on their home screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but I'll give it a try:

1. There is no way to start an application automatically after it was installed.

   There is the [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) Broadcast Intent, but the application being installed doesn't receive this.
2. Android applications can not add App Widgets to the home screen. Applications can define App Widgets, but user has to add them manually to the home screen.